I'd like to dispute a closure "How do you figure out what CPUs are compatible with a Desktop?"
Question in question here
While I've got the power to reopen it unilaterally, I've answered the question, and I think I'd like to take the opportunity to bring this up on meta.
While in general shopping questions are off topic here - I'd like to bring up the original reasoning
OP's asked a general enough question - as opposed to asking what processor specifically they can use, they asked for guidelines in what can be used. To paraphrase Jeff "ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy."
That's what they've done. They've explained where the gap in their knowledge is - and what they need to know. The answer isn't a product, and can't be.
It feels like a textbook case of a good product related question.
As such, could I ask folks have a look and vote appropriately?

I would vote, but mine is binding ... I'll wait for a few reopens before casting mine.

I would also vote, but don't have the required rep on this site.

Yeah, it feels like that close reason is sometimes used to broadly. I remeber i asked once what role Dolby actually played in home theater 5.1 audio, so i could assemble a chain of compatible devices (single PC mirrored out to two TVs each with 5.1 hardware via HDMI), but suffered an ignominious closure.  Sometimes I feel like i need to contort my question to keep casual readers from casting close votes. I don;t ask many questions, so not a huge deal, but it does seem like we're too quick to vote to close if something smells like a "what should I buy" question.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.
I voted to reopen the question and also upvoted it, as I'm in agreement that it's a quality question.
